# How to combine results of two SQL queries into one file using Powershell?

Tags: sql, excel, powershell, csv, ssms

There are a lot variations of this question out there but solutions are working.

Basically, in the for loop I need the result of both the queries to be appended in the same excel file. The picture of sample output is attached.

The idea is to get the result in one row from `$usedOnRnQuery` then move onto to the second query `$partRnQuery` becuase there are multiple rows returned for `$usedOnRn` in the second query.

```
$server = "ServerName"
    $database = "DBName"
    $combinedResults = @() 
    $csvFilePath="C:\Desktop\Scripts\CSVOutput\Output_EngBOMUsed_1.csv"
    $queryBOM = "Select Distinct UsedOnRn From [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngBOMHierarchy2_Aras] EBOMH"
    $invokeSqlBOM = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $queryBOM 
    
    foreach($row  in $invokeSqlBOM ){
        $usedOnRn = $row.UsedOnRn
        $usedOnRnQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT
        PartRn,
        PartNo AS SOURCE_PART_NUMBER,
        Revision AS SOURCE_PART_REVISION 
        FROM
        [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngParts_Aras]
        WHere PartRn = '$usedOnRn'
        "
    $invokeSqlusedOnRn = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query 
    $usedOnRnQuery

    $partRnQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT EBOMH.PartRn AS Child_PartRn, 
    EPA.Revision AS RELATED_PART_REVISION,
    EPA.PART_NUMBER AS RELATED_PART_NUMBER,
    EBOMH.QtyPerAssy AS QUATITY,
    EBOMH.UsedonRn    
    FROM [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngBOMHierarchy2_Aras] EBOMH
    Inner JOin [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngParts_TwoPartONly_Aras] EPA ON EPA.PartRn=EBOMH.PartRn
    Where EBOMH.UsedOnRn = '$usedOnRn'"

    $invokePartRn = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query 
    $partRnQuery

    $combinedObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    UsedOnRn               = $usedOnRn
    Source_Part_Number     = $invokeSqlusedOnRn.PartRn
    Source_Part_Revision   = $invokeSqlusedOnRn.SOURCE_PART_REVISION
    Related_Part_Number    = $invokePartRn.RELATED_PART_NUMBER
    Related_Part_Revision  = $invokePartRn.RELATED_PART_REVISION
    Quantity               = $invokePartRn.QUANTITY
    }
    $combinedResults += $combinedObject

    $combinedResults | Export-Excel -Path $csvFilePath -Append   
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @tinazmu that does not work at all.  In 'PartRn' 149977 has child parts that come from the second query. Joining the two queries does work because I want the "parent" part first, then all its children

Comment: * Correction, in the above comment I meant to "Joining the two queries DOESN'T work..."

Comment: You can achieve it with a single query joining these three queries, but sample DDL and data is needed. Only the part about presentation: blanking 'same'/repeating rows (for columns A,B,C in your output) is a little fiddly.